# jQuery event delegation does not work for me

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input with the class of `.mt-input-mini`

This input is generated after the page load by clicking some other elements.

I want to attach an event listener to this input, and thus I have used `on()` like this:

```
 $('.mt-input-mini').on("click", function(event){               
            alert("Something has been done.");
        })
```

But this does not work. Why? I want to `alert()` on the click-event of this input.

Comment: You're not using event delegation. You're attempting to bind directly to the elements. jQuery should have kept its event delegation separate by requiring `.delegate()` instead of overloading `.on()`. It causes too much confusion for people, but jQuery is addicted to overloading.

Comment: check if you get any messages in your console window (F12).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to add a handler to something that doesn't yet exist.

Event delegation involves adding the handler to something that *does*, and watching for events happening *within* that container:

```
$(document.body).on('click', '.mt-input-mini', function(event) {
  alert("Something has been done.");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/3CP7h/ you can find working example

Make sure you have:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.js"></script>
```

in head section of your html code

HTML

```
<button class='mt-input-mini'>Trigger custom event</button>
```

JavaScript

```
 $('.mt-input-mini').on("click", function (event) {
     alert("Something has been done.");
 });
```